# Как остановить счетчик и обработать IndexOutOfRangeException?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq

Здравствуйте.

Есть метод, с помощью которого осуществляется переход на следующую запись в XML файле, который проиходит при нажатии на кнопку. Внутри метода есть счетчик, который получает текущую позицию элемента в XML. Как запретить увеличение счетчика или остановить его при достижении последнего элемента массива?

```
public void Next()
{
    string[] files = { "A.xml", "B.xml" };

    Dictionary<string, string[]> values = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
         XDocument main = XDocument.Load(file);

        var terms = main
            .Descendants("Root")
            .Descendants("Statya")
            .Select(x => x.Value)
            .ToArray();

        values[file] = terms;
    }

    current++;

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            textBox1.Text = values[file][current];
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
        {
            textBox1.Text = values[file][current];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете проверять в самом обработчике события величину счетчика. Если максимальная величина достигнута, то не вызывайте метод `void Next()`.
Кроме того можно заблокировать кнопку `button.Enable = False`, чтобы нажать на нее было невозможно. 
Также я бы советовал не читать файл каждый раз при нажатии кнопки - прочтите его 1 раз при создании соответствующего класса, а потом обращайтесь к массиву (в вашем случае словарю `values`)

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить, не превышает ли значение счетчика количество элементов в массивах, и если не превышает, то нарастить счетчик:

```
int length = values.Min(v => v.Value.Length);

if (current + 1 < length)
    current++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ловить `IndexOutOfRangeException` — недостойное занятие. Вы **можете** узнать, какие индексы есть в массиве, а значит, **можете** обратиться к массиву так, чтобы оно не произошло.

Кроме того, вы присваиваете значение в `textBox1.Text` несколько раз, это тоже неправильно.

Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
string currentFile;
int current;
public bool Next()
{
    var records = values[currentFile];
    if (current >= records.Length - 1)
        return false;

    current++;
    textBox1.Text = records[current];
    return true;
}
```